# Support for Private Endpoint usage for IoT Hub and Device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-private-link

I am trying to access IoT Hub from a device via private endpoint.
So basically, all public access to IoT Hub is denied and I have allowed private access to this IoT Hub only through a private endpoint.

This private endpoint has it's own subnet and it sits between the IoT Hub and device.
I am simulating data using C# wherein I am using Symmetric keys for device to IoT Hub authentication.

**So do I need to change the device connection string hostname from "HostName=HubName.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=deviceName;SharedAccessKey=KeyAlphabets" to something else ?**

(Because this device will be pointing to the endpoint instead of IoT Hub)

If yes, then with what should I replace this connection string  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to connect the IOT edge device (Centos OS) to IOT hub with Private Endpoint associated to the VNET.

Here are the suggestions:

Configure DNS Conditional Forwarder on the On-Premises DNS Servers which will forward the queries back to an Azure VM running DNS Services. This Azure VM will also need a DNS Conditional Forwarder configuration which will forward the queries to Azure DNS (168.63.129.16).

DNS Query Flow: Azure VM -> On-Prem DNS Servers -> Azure VM Running DNS Services -> Azure DNS (168.63.129.16)

Create Forward Lookup Zones and create A Record entries on the On-Premises DNS Servers.

Use Azure DNS Server (168.63.129.16) on the Azure VNet.

Use Azure DNS Server on the Azure VM’s NIC Card

Add local host file entries for IoT Hub FQDNs.